# JSF CDI Conversation scope

Tags: jsf, cdi

I have a problem with CDI scope.

I have a bean with conversation scoped, ClientController, where I have client and phone object to be push in a service order. When I register a new client, I can push one or more phones to this client. For this, I have used conversation scope. However each request to push a new phone to my client is executing the @PostContruct method, doing the bean lose its state, even I am giving begin on the conversation when I push the first phone.

At first, I guess the problem was the bean configuration, but when I removed the template that was declared on the client page, the application works correct. This template use a bean with session scope, to control the page language by the user choice.

Next has my code, and you can follow my code on github repository by this link https://github.com/mcqueide/service-order.

**ClientController.java**

```
package br.com.codeshare.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import br.com.codeshare.enums.ErrorCode;
import br.com.codeshare.exception.BusinessException;
import br.com.codeshare.model.Client;
import br.com.codeshare.model.Phone;
import br.com.codeshare.qualifiers.SessionMap;
import br.com.codeshare.service.ClientService;
import br.com.codeshare.service.PhoneService;
import br.com.codeshare.util.WebResources;

@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class ClientController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;
    @Inject @SessionMap
    private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;
    @Inject
    private ClientService clientService;

    private Client newClient;

    @Inject
    private PhoneController phoneController;
    @Inject
    private PhoneService phoneService;

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    private String filterName;

    private List<Client> listClients;

    private Client clientSelected;
    private List<Phone> phoneToBeRemove;

    @Produces
    @Named
    public Client getNewClient() {
        return newClient;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initNewClient() {
        newClient = new Client();
        newClient.setTelefones(new ArrayList<Phone>());
        listClients = clientService.findAll();
    }

    public String save() throws Exception {
        try {
            validatePhoneLeastOnePhoneObligatory(newClient);

            clientService.save(newClient);
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, WebResources.getMessage("register"),WebResources.getMessage("sucess_register")));
            initNewClient();
        }catch (BusinessException e) {
            FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,WebResources.getMessage(e.getErrorCode()),"");
            facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = getRootErrorMessage(e);
            FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,errorMessage,WebResources.getMessage("unsuccessful"));
            facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
        }
        if(!conversation.isTransient()){
            conversation.end();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String update(Client client) throws Exception{
        try {
            validatePhoneLeastOnePhoneObligatory(client);

            clientService.update(client,phoneToBeRemove);
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,  WebResources.getMessage("register"),WebResources.getMessage("sucess_register")));
            initNewClient();
        }catch (BusinessException e) {
            FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,WebResources.getMessage(e.getErrorCode()),"");
            facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = getRootErrorMessage(e);
            FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, WebResources.getMessage("unsuccessful"));
            facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
            return null;
        }
        if(!conversation.isTransient()){
            conversation.end();
        }
        return "clients";
    }

    private void validatePhoneLeastOnePhoneObligatory(Client client) throws BusinessException {
        if(client.getHomePhone().isEmpty() && client.getBisenessPhone().isEmpty()){
            throw new BusinessException(ErrorCode.LEAST_ONE_PHONE_OBLIGATORY.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    private String getRootErrorMessage(Exception e) {
        String errorMessage = "Registration failed. See server log for more information";
        if (e == null) {
            return errorMessage;
        }

        Throwable t = e;
        while (t != null) {
            errorMessage = t.getLocalizedMessage();
            t = t.getCause();
        }
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void addClientPhone() {
        if(conversation.isTransient()){
            conversation.begin();
        }

        phoneController.getNewPhone().setClient(newClient);
        if (newClient.getPhones() == null) {
            newClient.setTelefones(new ArrayList<Phone>());
        }
        newClient.getPhones().add(phoneController.getNewPhone());
        phoneController.initNewPhone();
    }

    public void removeClientPhone(Phone phone){
        if(conversation.isTransient()){
            conversation.begin();
        }

        clientSelected.getPhones().remove(phone);
        if(phoneToBeRemove == null){
            phoneToBeRemove = new ArrayList<Phone>();
        }
        phoneToBeRemove.add(phone);
    }

    public void addClientPhoneOnUpdate() {
        if(conversation.isTransient()){
            conversation.begin();
        }

        phoneController.getNewPhone().setClient(clientSelected);
        if (clientSelected.getPhones() == null) {
            clientSelected.setTelefones(new ArrayList<Phone>());
        }
        clientSelected.getPhones().add(phoneController.getNewPhone());
        phoneController.initNewPhone();
    }

    public void searchByName() {
        listClients = null;
        if(filterName == null){
            listClients = clientService.findAll();
        }
        listClients = clientService.findByName(filterName);
    }

    public String edit(Client client) {
        if(conversation.isTransient()){
            conversation.begin();
        }
        this.clientSelected = client;
        List<Phone> phoneList = phoneService.findPhoneByClientId(clientSelected.getId());
        clientSelected.setTelefones(phoneList);
        sessionMap.put("client", client);
        return "update_client";
    }

    public Client getClientSelected() {
        return (Client) sessionMap.get("client");
    }

    public String getFilterName() {
        return filterName;
    }

    public void setFilterName(String filterName) {
        this.filterName = filterName;
    }

    public List<Client> getListClients() {
        return listClients;
    }

}
```

**Language.java**

```
package br.com.codeshare.util;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Language implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        localeCode = "pt";
        countryLocaleCodeChanged();
    }

    private String localeCode;

    public String getLocaleCode() {
        return localeCode;
    }

    public void setLocaleCode(String localeCode) {
        this.localeCode = localeCode;
    }

    // value change event listener
    public void countryLocaleCodeChanged() {
        facesContext.getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(localeCode));
    }
}
```

**client.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" template="/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="titulo">
        #{label['client.title']}
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:messages />
            <p:fieldset legend="#{label['client.fieldset.client']}" id="client">
                <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="panelGrid-semBorda">
                    <p:outputLabel for="name" value="#{label['client.name']}" />
                    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{newClient.name}" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="adress" value="#{label['client.adress']}" />
                    <p:inputText id="adress" value="#{newClient.adress}" />

                    <p:fragment rendered='#{!language.localeCode.equals("en")}'>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="panelGrid-semBorda">
                            <p:outputLabel for="homePhone_pt" value="#{label['client.homePhone']}" />
                            <p:inputMask id="homePhone_pt" value="#{newClient.homePhone}" mask="(99)99999-9999"/>

                            <p:outputLabel for="bisenessPhone_pt" value="#{label['client.businessPhone']}" />
                            <p:inputMask id="bisenessPhone_pt" value="#{newClient.bisenessPhone}" mask="(99)9999-9999"/>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:fragment>

                    <p:fragment rendered='#{language.localeCode.equals("en")}'>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="panelGrid-semBorda">
                            <p:outputLabel for="homePhone_en" value="#{label['client.homePhone']}" />
                            <p:inputText id="homePhone_en" value="#{newClient.homePhone}"/>

                            <p:outputLabel for="bisenessPhone_en" value="#{label['client.businessPhone']}" />
                            <p:inputText id="bisenessPhone_en" value="#{newClient.bisenessPhone}"/>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:fragment>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
            <p:fieldset legend="#{label['client.fieldset.phone']}" id="phones">
                <p:panelGrid id="phone" columns="1" styleClass="panelGrid-semBorda">
                    <p:outputLabel for="brand" value="#{label['phone.brand']}" />
                    <p:inputText id="brand" value="#{newPhone.brand}" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="model" value="#{label['phone.model']}" />
                    <p:inputText id="model" value="#{newPhone.model}" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="state" value="#{label['phone.state']}"/>
                    <p:selectOneRadio id="state" value="#{newPhone.state}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{phoneStates}" var="p" itemValue="#{p}" itemLabel="#{label[p.label]}" />
                    </p:selectOneRadio>

                    <p:outputLabel for="esn" value="#{label['phone.esn']}" />
                    <p:inputText id="esn" value="#{newPhone.esn}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="#{label['phone.add']}" action="#{clientController.addClientPhone}" update="phoneTable phones"/>

                <p:dataTable value="#{newClient.phones}" var="phone" emptyMessage="#{label['phone.notadd']}"
                    id="phoneTable">
                    <p:column headerText="#{label['phone.brand']}">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{phone.brand}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="#{label['phone.model']}">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{phone.model}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:fieldset>
            <p:commandButton action="#{clientController.save}" value="#{label['client.save']}" update="@form"/>


        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**template.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<f:view locale="#{language.localeCode}" encoding="utf-8">
<h:head>
    <title>
        <ui:insert name="title"/>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" />
</h:head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="menu">
            <ui:include src="/menu.xhtml" />
        </div>  

        <div id="body">
            <ui:insert name="body"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

**menu.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition>
        <p:menubar>
            <p:submenu label="#{label['menu.serviceorder']}">
                <p:menuitem value="#{label['menu.serviceorder']}" url="/service-order.jsf"/>
                <p:menuitem value="#{label['menu.serviceorder.new']}" url="/new-service-order.jsf"/>
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu label="#{label['menu.client']}">
                <p:menuitem value="#{label['menu.client.new']}" url="/client.jsf"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="#{label['menu.clients']}" url="/clients.jsf"></p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>
        </p:menubar>
        <h:form class="menu_languages">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{language.localeCode}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Português" itemValue="pt" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en" />
                <p:ajax listener="#{language.countryLocaleCodeChanged}" update="@all" />                        
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty convinced that you are running into one of the following problems:

- Conversation ends

  - try to play with some `@PreDestroy` methods to see when does the conversation vanish
  - make sure you do not `end()` conversations earlier (checking your code that would mean calling `save`/`update`)
- New conversation is created every time you add phone (this is most likely the cause)

  - when you want another request to be associated with your running conversation, you need to make use of conversation ID (propagate it)
  - note that you can obtain the ID by calling `conversation.getId()`
  - to verify this, check that your URL contains the given conversation ID
  - also note that if you every time create a new Conversation, the old long-running ones are still hanging in there

Propagation of Conversation is done by appending a `cid` (conversation ID) to the request URL. Here is a quote from [CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#conversation_context) (which I suggest you read) explaining when is conversation propagated automatically:

> If the current Servlet request is a JSF request, and the conversation is in long-running state, it is propagated according to the following rules:
>
> - The long-running conversation context associated with a request that renders a JSF view is automatically propagated to any faces request (JSF form submission) that originates from that rendered page.
> - The long-running conversation context associated with a request that results in a JSF redirect (a redirect resulting from a navigation rule or JSF NavigationHandler) is automatically propagated to the resulting non-faces request, and to any other subsequent request to the same URL. This is accomplished via use of a request parameter named cid containing the unique identifier of the conversation.

Comment: I have realized that the problem isn’t the template as I have pointed on first message, I have done a lot of tests, and when I remove the tag <h:head> from the template, my scope works correct, and don’t start the @PostContruct, and I can see the cid parameter on my URL. But I need the <h:head> to declare my css, so how can I correct this situation? JSF have one tag to correct this statement? Or how can I put the CID on URL parameter?

Comment: When you start the conversation, that is when you add the phone, you can try to force re-render of **the whole `form`** (`<h:form id="form">`) which is supposed to work with the CID. Or namely all components that are going to be using that CID. That way any further actions invoked from that form should have a CID linked to them (automatically propagated). I would try to avoid manually putting CID anywhere unless really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolved this with this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{clientController.initConversation()}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

Now when my page is render, I have my cid on my post action.  But I don’t know if it is the better way to resolve this, because I want to transform my transaction in long-running just when the user click to add a phone, so if someone has a better idea, share please.